# Keyboard not responding during boot

Tags: keyboard, motherboard

My keyboard just stopped responding during boot. So I cannot go to BIOS or select system which I want to start. It is USB keyboard and it was working before. I borrowed PS2 keyboard and it also isn't working during boot.

Lately I have been having problems with hard disk. Once every 2-5 minutes LED was on for 30 seconds and win7 wasn't responsive. I connected disk to another controller on motherboard and seems it is working now. All that suggests that to me that that motherboard is broken. What can I check? Or maybe you have some other suggestions?

**Edit:**
For last 3-5 days I have been having problems with video driver. Computer can work for hours without any problem and then suddenly I have 'Display driver amdkmdap stopped responding and has successfully recovered.' every one or two minutes. And then it works ok again. But my keyboard wasn't responding during boot long before graphics driver problems.

Comment: I doubt it is motherboard, simply because *typically* hardware either works or fails! When the PC does run do you have a problem with the keyboard or is it only non-responsive during the boot?

Comment: after windows loads keyboard is working without any problems.

Comment: Are you able to flash the bios - some manufacturers allow it to be set up from the OS and it does it automatically on reboot. Also, if you put in a recovery CD, does the mouse work then?

Comment: My Gigabyte mainboard allows flashing BIOS from windows, never tried it. It also contains backup BIOS that is used to automatically restore main BIOS if it is broken. So I don't think this is BIOS' problem. Also look at my edit please.

Comment: OK - short of trying each piece of hardware one at a time, it's going to be difficult to solve. In this instance, I would test my GPU/PSU/RAM/Processor in another PC (if you can - easier said than done) and if that is OK, get a new motherboard.

Comment: So I flashed BIOS, everything went fine untill restart. PC is not starting. Not even single beep during boot. So now I see how Gigabyte's DUAL Bios works. It doesn't. So I think the easiest way to check whether all my problems were bacause of mainboard is to buy a new one now.

Comment: Last thing. Take out battery on Motherboard  for 2 minutes then try again.

Comment: What does that have any chance of working? I was sure after failure during BIOS flash mainboard is trash.

Answer (score 0):

On some motherboards, only some of the USB ports are enabled during pre-boot. If there are multiple clusters of USB ports (like a cluster of 2 ports and one of 4 ports), the smaller number cluster seems to work during pre-boot. But in any case, try several of them.
Also, if it has a jack for an older style keyboard and you have one, you could try that to get into the bios screen to check that the USB option for pre-boot older style USB compatibility isn't effecting it.

Comment: I said that I tried PS2 keyboard and also it doesn't work during boot. Will try to switch USB ports. I think I have already tried it but I did not try all of them.